# Converting Hex Values to Plain Text

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

```
_0xcebfx1e
_0xcebfx1f
```

What kind of Numbers are those

and how to convert them back to Plain Text.

Comment: What integer should _0xcebfx1e represent? The 2nd x means its not a valid hex litteral, is it 2 values?

Comment: No... this is one value "_0xcebfx1e" and this "_0xcebfx1f" is another value.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what they are? Where did you find them? In what context were they used. As Alex said, they're not hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Got these values through Javascript Obfuscater/Packer

All Variables turned into these values.

Comment: Does the packer have a unpacker? What are ultimately you trying to do?

Comment: I want the exact variable names back.
No UnPacker.... Used JSBeautfier but these values can't convert to plain text.